# Listen to javascript calls of a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I has the following HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" onClick="anyJSFunction('Test')">
</div>
```

And I open it on a WebView like:

```
        web = new WebView(this);

        WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);
        settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        web.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/test.html");
```

Now I want to listen on Java when 'anyJSFunction' is called and also be able to get it arguments.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a decent example in the documentation for [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). Look for "Binding JavaScript code to Android code."

You'll build a class as an interface from JavaScript to Java/Android. You create an instance and pass it to the WebView. Then the JavaScript code can reference the class instance by name.

Comment: Well.. this is what I'm looking for. Ty!